# How best to encrypt an AMOUNT column in MYSQL and Laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel, encryption, aes

I have attached a section of a database table with an Amounts field.

At some point, someone with database credentials logged in and made manual changes to the amounts.

I would love it if I could encrypt these amounts in a way that they can only be decrypted using a laravel code.

I can encrypt using AES but I am not sure if this is the best option or if it would impact the performance of the queries.

Even if I managed to start encrypting now, how would I encrypt the already existing data to maintain integrity?

[image]

Comment: If you aren't decrypting in SQL it shouldn't impact queries there. Decrypting in SQL isn't too resource intensive, depending on how large your data set is. Could look at https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/encryption.

Comment: @user3783243 thank you for your response. Looked at it and it seems feasible. 
Is it possible to encrypt the existing records?

Comment: I am voting to close it as its opinion based.  The solution is to not let anyone change the raw data with a database workbench.  Have different users for admin and usage.  And ensure that all changes are made through your front end and that you log the changes.

Comment: Well, then the naughty guy writes Laravel code to decrypt, modify, and reencrypt.  That is encryption will not solve your problem.